# How to exclude the first line from a text file using php

Tags: php, mysql, text-files, fopen, fgets

My text file sample.txt. I want to exclude the first row from the text file and store the other rows into mysql database.

```
ID Name EMail

1  Siva xyz@gmail.com

2 vinoth xxx@gmail.com

3 ashwin yyy@gmail.com
```

Now I want to read this data from the text file except the first row(ID,name,email) and store into the MYsql db.Because already I have created a filed in database with the same name.

```
I have tried
$handle = @fopen($filename, "r"); //read line one by one

while (!feof($handle)) // Loop till end of file.
{
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096); // Read a line.
}
print_r($buffer); // It shows all the text.
```

Please let me know how to do this?

Thanks.
 Regards,
 Siva R

Comment: It looks like `$buffer` should only hold the last line after that while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `fgets` once before your while loop to get the header row out of the way.

```
$firstline = fgets($handle, 4096);
while (!feof($handle)) // Loop till end of file.
{ ...
```

Answer (score 2):

---

It's easier if you use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) since it will get all rows in an array instead:

```
// Get all rows in an array (and tell file not to include the trailing new lines
$rows = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

// Remove the first element (first row) from the array
array_shift($rows);

// Now do what you want with the rest
foreach ($rows as $lineNumber => $row) {
    // do something cool with the row data
}
```

If you want to get it all as a string again, without the first row, just implode it with a new line as glue:

```
// The rows still contain the line break, since we only trimmed the copy
$content = implode("\n", $rows);
```

> ***Note:*** As @Don'tPanic pointed out in his comment, using `file()` is simple and easy but **not** advisable if the original file is large, since it will read the whole thing into memory as an array (and arrays take more memory than strings). He also correctly recommended the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES-flag, just so you know :-)

Comment: I agree `file` is handy, although it may not be best to try to read the entire file all at once if it's very large. (Looks like you have a little typo in your `array_shift`, btw.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic - Yes, it would be foolish to use it with a large file. Best to point it out. I did not know about the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`-flag. Cheers! Hmm.. I might be blind, but I can't see the typo?